# Polars apply to all values (including nulls)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

I have a column in a dataset which has `null` (which are to be predicted), and some other ones.
I wanted to create a `is_null` column which says whether the first column's values were null or not (element-wise).

I came across `.apply` method, but it "skipped" the null values. Here's the example:

```py
import polars as pl


df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, None, 3], "bar": [-1, None, 8]})
df.head()

# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌──────┬──────┐
# │ foo  ┆ bar  │
# │ ---  ┆ ---  │
# │ i64  ┆ i64  │
# ╞══════╪══════╡
# │ 1    ┆ -1   │
# ├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
# │ null ┆ null │
# ├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
# │ 3    ┆ 8    │
# └──────┴──────┘

def print_and_fill(value):
    print("Value is", value)
    return 1

df["foo"].apply(print_and_fill)

## Output ##
# Value is 1
# Value is 8

# shape: (3,)
# Series: 'bar' [i64]
# [
#   1
#   null
#   1
# ]
```

Clearly, the null value was skipped. Is there any way to apply the function to **all** values?

I came across a workaround: We can temporarily `.fill_null()` and then call `.apply()`, but this is clearly not the best solution.

Comment: Please add library you are using ( **pl** is object with clear methods, so its probably class or library) in tag and in tittle. It would help to not misdirect core of an issue so you actually get an answer. 

*Also , if you could, rephrasing the question would help also.* 

On the other side, NULL/None are often disregarded by any filtering functions and this is for a reason. It is rarely a placeholder but it means that something has gone extremely wrong. It tends to go Integer ( 0 False, 1 True) then None/Null/nullptr in terms of change. You can try filter function tho, might help.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to create a is_null column which says whether the first column's values were null or not (element-wise).

One easy way is to use the [`is_null`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.is_null.html) expression.  For example:

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('foo').is_null().alias('foo_is_null')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ foo  ┆ bar  ┆ foo_is_null │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ bool        │
╞══════╪══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ -1   ┆ false       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ null ┆ true        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 8    ┆ false       │
└──────┴──────┴─────────────┘
```

In general, it's best to avoid using `apply` unless absolutely necessary.